# What is the best solution for organising test scripts required to pass a new feature/release

Tags: testing

Has anyone experience with good software (or another way) of organising the individual tes scripts which need to be passed before a feature or whole release can be released to customers? I've heard good things about this http://www.rallydev.com/agile_products/lifecycle_management/test_management/ but am yet to use it myself. I know a lot of people use excel to organise test scripts but I'd like something which multiple people can work on simultaneously and is really designed for the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of test management solutions out there.  It really depends on your needs and how much you want to spend, etc...  I am partial to [TOMOS](http://reachsimplicity.com), a hosted web app designed for test teams. It supports the whole test cycle (requirements, test cases, test execution, bug tracking and reporting).  (n.b. I do work for the company that makes TOMOS, but I've used most of what's out there, so I think I have a pretty well-rounded opinion.)

Comment: Tom, do you know if Tomos allows you to drop screenshots or videos into your test cases? I sometimes find text descriptions for test cases aren't enough, particularly if the testers are not as familiar with the system as the test author.

Comment: ninesided, tomos does allow you to attach files to test cases.